# jQuery getting specific properties of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of image elements, I want to find the biggest height value.

So, if I have

```
[
    <img src="image1.jpg" width="300" height="400" />, 
    <img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="500" />,
    <img src="image3.jpg" width="100" height="200" />
]
```

The number that I want is `500`.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this strategy, assuming your images are stored in the array "imgs":

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply({}, imgs.map(function(x){return x.height}));
maxHeight; // => 500
```

Comment: The code isn't quite right, but the idea behind it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you really have an array of `img` element instances (what you've shown could be taken either way, elements or strings, but you haven't quoted them, so...).

You can also use jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var maxHeight = -1;
$.each(theArray, function() {
    if (maxHeight < this.height) {
        maxHeight = this.height;
    }
});
```

Or if you already have the array wrapped in a jQuery object:

```
var theArray = $('img'); // A jQuery object wrapped around an array of all `img`s
```

...then you can use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (which is slightly different from `$.each`):

```
var maxHeight = -1;
theArray.each(function() {
    if (maxHeight < this.height) {
        maxHeight = this.height;
    }
});
```

Or just use a boring old-fashioned loop:

```
var index, maxHeight;
maxHeight = -1;
for (index = 0; index < theArray.length; ++index) {
    if (maxHeight < theArray[index].height) {
        maxHeight < theArray[index].height;
    }
}
```

In all of the above, I've used the [`height` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-91561496) of the [`HTMLImageElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-17701901) as specified by the DOM. Alternately, you may prefer jQuery's [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function (if so, don't forget to wrap the element in a jQuery object — e.g., `$(this).height()`), but normally `height` (the property) is all you need with `img` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your images are in an array called a:

```
a.sort(function(a,b) {return $(a).height() < $(b).height() } ) ; 
alert($(a[0]).height()) ;
```

Make sure you have single quotes around your image tags:

```
a = [
   '<img src="image1.jpg" width="300" height="400" />', 
    '<img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="500" />',
    '<img src="image3.jpg" width="100" height="200" />'
] ;
```

Comment: This works fine but if the array is really long then performance of this solution will poor, since it is `O(n*lg(n))`, whereas others are `O(n)`.  But in reality, probably doesn't matter for a "small" number of images.